# Active MQ Timeout time

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I am creating a listener using activemq-cpp library on linux side. However, the java activemq broker on windows side (server runs on windows) breaks the connection after 30 seconds.

The error message is :

`Transport Connection to : tcp://x.y.z.w failed: InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too <30000> long: tcp://x.y.z.w:12345`

Now according to activemq documentation I have tried following:

1. Setting the connection url to following while creating connection:
   `"tcp://x.y.z.w:61616?transport.useInactivityMonitor=false"/>`
2. In the activemq.xml file I have set the following

   `<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600;transport.useInactivityMonitor=false"/>`

However, I still get disconnected after **30** seconds.

Are there more settings that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The `maxInactivityDuration=0` should be set only in `activemq.xml` file.

And the `delimiter` option in `url` is : `&amp;` and not `&`

Answer (score 1):

You can use socket.useInactivityMonitor=false as well. This needs to be done on client and server side.